# Keep the order of the JSON keys during JSON conversion to CSV

Tags: java, json, csv

I am using the JSON library provided here http://www.json.org/java/index.html to convert a json string I have to CSV.
But the problem I have is, the order of the keys is lost after conversion.

This is the conversion code:

```
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(someString);
    JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("items");
    String s = CDL.toString(ja);
    System.out.println(s);
```

This is the content of "someString":

```
{
    "items":
    [
        {
            "WR":"qwe",
            "QU":"asd",
            "QA":"end",
            "WO":"hasd",
            "NO":"qwer"
        },
    ]
}
```

This is the result:

```
WO,QU,WR,QA,NO
hasd,asd,qwe,end,qwer
```

While what I expect is to keep the order of the keys:

```
WR,QU,QA,WO,NO
qwe,asd,end,hasd,qwer
```

Is there any way I can have this result using this library? If not, is there any other library that will provide the capability to keep the order of keys in the result?

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted. I don't even think JSON guarantees order.

Comment: thanks for the info. But I have no choice but to use JSON in my application and my application needs to keep the order of the keys :(

Comment: In my case the issue isn't the lack of an order but that it is non-deterministic. Sometimes I get key `foo` before key `bar` and sometimes `bar` before `foo`. This makes it difficult to write tests for.

Comment: I've also encountered this need, but it's for fast log comparison during real-time testing. I need to compare newly generated logs to previously generated logs in real-time for a high through-put application. There are other ways to do it, but I'd prefer the logs be in JSON format. However, to minimize CPU use, I'm writing my own direct-to-string JSON writer. I don't need the internal structure at all, and I can maintain key order for fast string comparisons of logs. There are good reasons to want predictable order.

Comment: write your own code to convert JSON to a specificaly ordered CSV file, that way you respect what both formats are supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.

I used the JSON.simple library from here https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ to read the JSON string to keep the order of keys and use JavaCSV library from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/ to convert to CSV format.

Comment: I'm surprised that this worked.  According to my reading of both the code and comments of the JSONObject class (https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java), it doesn't do anything to preserve the order of the keys.

Comment: I didn't specify the full solution here, but the gist of it is that json-simple provides a factory with which you can specify the data structure used to store json objects. Simply specify to use LinkedHashMap.

Comment: @Hery,I'm facing the same issue but I couldn't solve it. I use `org.json` to convert `List<LinkedHahMap>` to `JSONArray` in order to create a `CSV`, the `CSV` is created but not in the same order as my `List `. I've tried to use the two lib you present here, but I couldn't find the methods to convert to `CSV`.Could you please give more details.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did exactly?

Comment: hello, I can't get the jar anymore since its link is no more working. If anyone can help, please!

Answer (score 105):

There are (hacky) ways to do it ... but you shouldn't.

In JSON, an object is defined thus:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

See http://json.org.

Most implementations of JSON make no effort to preserve the order of an object's name/value pairs, since it is (by definition) not significant.

If you want order to be preserved, you need to redefine your data structure; e.g.

```
{
    "items":
    [
        [
            {"WR":"qwe"},
            {"QU":"asd"},
            {"QA":"end"},
            {"WO":"hasd"},
            {"NO":"qwer"}
        ],
    ]
}
```

or more simply:

```
{
    "items":
    [
        {"WR":"qwe"},
        {"QU":"asd"},
        {"QA":"end"},
        {"WO":"hasd"},
        {"NO":"qwer"}
    ]
}
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> Thanks for the info, but I have no choice but to use JSON in my application and my application needs to keep the order of the keys regardless of the definition of JSON object... I am not allowed to change the format of the JSON file as well...

You need to have a hard conversation with whoever designed that file structure and won't let you change it.  It is / they are plain wrong.  You *need* to convince them.

If they *really* won't let you change it:

- You should insist on *not* calling it JSON ... 'cos it isn't.
- You should point out that you are going to have to write / modify code specially to handle this "not JSON" format ... unless you can find some JSON implementation that preserves the order.  If they are a paying client, make sure that they pay for this extra work you have to do.
- You should point out that if the "not JSON" needs to be used by some other tool, it is going to be problematic.  Indeed, this problem will occur over and over ...

This kind of thing as really bad.  On the one hand, your software will be violating a well established / long standing specification that is designed to promote interoperability.  On the other hand, the nit-wits who designed this lame (not JSON!) file format are probably slagging off other people's systems etc 'cos the systems cannot cope with *their* nonsense.

**UPDATE**

It is also worth reading what the [JSON RFC (RFC 7159)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) says on this subject.  Here are some excerpts:

> In the years since the publication of RFC 4627, JSON has found very
> wide use.  This experience has revealed certain patterns, which,
> while allowed by its specifications, have caused interoperability
> problems.

> JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a text format for the
> serialization of structured data.  ...

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans,
> and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.

> JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or
> not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling
> software.  Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member
> ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be
> affected by these differences.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I have no choice but to use JSON in my application and my application needs to keep the order of the keys regardless of the definition of JSON object... I am not allowed to change the format of the JSON file as well...

Comment: Just noticed your edit. I appreciate the advice, but the "JSON-like" format really cannot be changed... So I just have to suck it up haha

Comment: @StephenC : Nice answer. I am struggling with the same problem and its creating duplicity in my paginated ListView. What the heck !!! No solutions ?

Comment: @YogeshSomani - the "solution" is to get hold of a proper JSON library, and "hack" it so that it preserves the key order.  See gary's answer for an example.  But you shouldn't expect a standard JSON library to do this because it is a BAD IDEA to encourage abuse of the JSON specification like this.  The real solution is to fix your application to use JSON properly.

Comment: its great to be purest and absolute, but let's not kid ourselves, there are real world scenarios where a JSON file needs its ordering of its defined values preserved. To pass and accept them in any order is a fundamental json approach, but I consider that dfferent than the ability to be able to take a json document and serialize / deserialize in equality. It's a common use case to have to take a json document and use it to form a document of another standard WDDX, HTML, etc where ordering needs to be preserved

Comment: @AndrewNorman - If what you said about "need" was really true, then the specification should be and would have been changed.  The reality is that it is easy to represent ordering in other ways in JSON.

Comment: The JSON information model declares JSON to be unordered, but we all know that the JSON serialization string is necessarily ordered. Requirements can apply at the information model level or at the representation level. I have an optimization requirement that is best met by guaranteeing serialization order -- see my comment about real-time testing in the OP.

Comment: JSON only requires that information not be encoded in the order of keys; it's not JSON otherwise. Consistency of serialization is a different issue. Within a single app, consistency can usually be guaranteed by using a common JSON library, but there are exceptions, such as when a single solution spans multiple platforms or frameworks. In these cases, you either have to find a way to deal with the inconsistency (introducing inefficiency), or you find a way to ensure consistency. Both approaches are valid.

Comment: *"JSON only requires that information not be encoded in the order of keys; it's not JSON otherwise."*.  I think you wrote that incorrectly.  The correct statement is that "JSON does not require that information is encoded in the order of the keys".  There is an big difference between these two statements ....

Comment: It really is a simple need... a LOT of common programming tools use JSON for config, and that JSON gets checked into source control. If you need to automatically update those configs in a devops pipeline, you REALLY do not want to have the order inside the JSON files be _randomized_ and re-checked in to source on _every_ pipeline run. This is problem for very standard simple tools such as npm (package.json) or typescript (tsconfig.json). It REALLY isn't some exotic company need. It can of course be argued that JSON was a bad choice of format for these tools... _but here we are!_ Too late!

Comment: "Too late!" - Yes.  In English, there is a saying: "A good workman doesn't blame his tools."  (I am referring to JSON as the tool in this context.)   As noted previously, JSON can represent ordered things. But you need to use a JSON array to do it.

Comment: @StephenC Stumbled across this thread ... does key order matter to a computer? No. Does it matter to documentation, UI, a human, etc. Yup, it sure does. Surely you have to agree that "username" and "password" belong together rather then one at the top and one at the bottom? There's a reason why Spring, etc. serialize out in order. Some implementations PURPOSELY make then unordered (like org.json) because they are "spec nazis". That's cool. Gson preserves order because they know that's the most common use case. So bye bye org.json :).

Comment: *"Surely you have to agree that "username" and "password" belong together rather then one at the top and one at the bottom?"* - No I don't.  In fact, as a user (of a typical API) I probably don't care about the order of the parameters.  But that that's not really the issue.  And computers do what they are told.  The real issue is programmers and the software that they write and that they depend.

Comment: *"Some implementations PURPOSELY make then unordered (like org.json) because they are "spec nazis"."* - Did you ask the implementors why?  Did they >say< that?  Other possible explanations are that a JSON stack *could* be faster, smaller, simpler if you don't need to preserve order end-to-end.  And bear in mind that when you use JSON in a public API, there are (at least) two JSON implementations involved; on the client side and the server side.  And possibly multiple programming languages.  For many folks "just use GSON everywhere" is not a solution ... cos they don't control "everywhere".

Answer (score 52):

It is quite simple to maintain order. I had the same problem with maintaining the order from DB layer to UI Layer.

Open JSONObject.java file. It internally uses HashMap which doesn't maintain the order.

Change it to LinkedHashMap:

```
    //this.map = new HashMap();
    this.map = new LinkedHashMap();
```

This worked for me. Let me know in the comments. I suggest the JSON library itself should have another JSONObject class which maintains order, like JSONOrderdObject.java. I am very poor in choosing the names.

Comment: svn checkout json-simple. modify file org.json.simple.JSONObject, <code>JOSNObject extends LinkedHashMap ...</code> from <code>.. HashMap..</code>, fix the imports and it works for me. v1.1.1.

Comment: This is a great one-line solution that I never would have thought to try. Works perfectly, and I didn't have to change any of my other code. +1

Comment: Great fix. You're a hero Sir

Comment: didn't work, I added the import, changed it like you said, even tried to do it like this: `this.map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();` still doesn't work. Please help ?

Comment: Haha really? Modifying the JSON library to meet your needs? I can just imagine this going down in company knowledge bases. "Do your mvn clean install, download the jar, find it, decompile it, then replace HashMap with LinkedHashMap". This will work great for multi developer teams (not).

Comment: Using LinkedHashMap in the library would add essentially no overhead and would break nothing.  I don't need things to be in order, but for regression testing, it's a lot easier if the keys come out in the same order they went in.

Comment: How do I override the jar file in my program, the JSONObject class of the jar file that contains a method public JSONObject(Map map)?

Comment: @ChrisNeve I don't see why "number of developers" affects whether you can use a locally forked copy of an existing library in your codebase.

Answer (score 29):

`JSONObject.java` takes whatever map you pass. It may be `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap` and  it will take `hashmap` only when the map is null .

Here is the constructor of `JSONObject.java` class that will do the checking of map.

```
 public JSONObject(Map paramMap)
  {
    this.map = (paramMap == null ? new HashMap() : paramMap);
  }
```

So before building a json object construct `LinkedHashMap` and then pass it to the constructor like this ,

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> jsonOrderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

jsonOrderedMap.put("1","red");
jsonOrderedMap.put("2","blue");
jsonOrderedMap.put("3","green");

JSONObject orderedJson = new JSONObject(jsonOrderedMap);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(orderedJson));

System.out.println("Ordered JSON Fianl CSV :: "+CDL.toString(jsonArray));
```

*So there is no need to change the `JSONObject.java` class  . Hope it helps somebody .*

Comment: Good answer, works for normal java, but doesn't work on android. I check the org.json.JSONObject in android, it's a pity that android still use hashmap created internally. It only copy name/value pairs from paramMap to HashMap... :(

Comment: I ordered JsonObject but When I try to add that object to an JsonArray it gives me unordered one. I need to put object to array , I need objects of array then I put header to array and sent back.  Ex: one object; 
    {CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID=611, CUSTOMER_NO=0000003204, CUSTOMER_NAME=MARMARİS - KARAS GIDA KARAS TÜKETİM MADDELERİ GIDA LOJ.}  
I get this If I put two object to array : [{"CUSTOMER_NAME":"SILA GIDA PAZARLAMA ","CUSTOMER_NO":"0000003122","CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID":"611"},{"CUSTOMER_NAME":"M":"0013114714","CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID":"611"}]
As you see it is wrong. How can I fix it

Comment: @Deepak Nagaraj . I've tried your solution but it didn't work, the `JSONObject` is not ordered as my `LinkedHashMap`. Are you usin `org.json` lib ?

Comment: This is not the `org.json` one.. It defines a `HashMap` internally, whatever the `Map` you give to it: @Deepak can you point us to the implementation you used?

Comment: This will not work with the `org.json` library. When you construct a new `JSONObject` object, passing a map as an argument, it will always be converted to a `HashMap`. The constructor firstly creates a new map: `this.map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`, and then loop over your map, copying every element to his `HashMap`.

Comment: How is this not the top-voted answer? The `JSONObject(Map)` constructor works like a charm (using org.json:json 20080701). Indeed, it may be a little bit of a hack to impose ordering on top of JSON, but there are genuine use cases for this which are not in any way an abuse of the JSON data model; consider serializing JSON to a file in version control, using the order to keep diffs small and meaningful.

Answer (score 16):

Another hacky solution using reflect:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
Field map = json.getClass().getDeclaredField("map");
map.setAccessible(true);//because the field is private final...
map.set(json, new LinkedHashMap<>());
map.setAccessible(false);//return flag
```

Comment: I didn't get your answer

Comment: The trick is to modify the class internally to use a LinkedHashMap instead of the default HashMap, making the JSON object have the data in the order you put them in, this is not directly sorted but it worked for me as the data parsed is already sorted.

Comment: looks good, but how to parse Json String AFTER map.set(json, new LinkedHashMap<>());  because Json String is passed in the constructor right? like, new JSONObject(jsonString).

Comment: Also, this didn't work. there is not field "map", there is a field "nameValuePairs" which is already LinckedHashMap, and it still doesnt work.

Comment: What implementation of the JSONObject are you using? I'm using org.json version 20140107 and had to preserve the ordering and thats how it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment about the string constructor, well after modifying the class via reflect you can naturally instantiate the object also via reflect like so: JSONObject.class.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("your string");

Answer (score 13):

A more verbose, but broadly applicable solution to this sort of problem is to use a pair of data structures: a list to contain the ordering, and a map to contain the relations.

For Example:

```
{
    "items":
    [
        {
            "WR":"qwe",
            "QU":"asd",
            "QA":"end",
            "WO":"hasd",
            "NO":"qwer"
        },
    ],
    "itemOrder":
        ["WR", "QU", "QA", "WO", "NO"]
}
```

You iterate the itemOrder list, and use those to look up the map values.  Ordering is preserved, with no kludges.

I have used this method many times.

Comment: This becomes complicated if your map isn't just simple key-value pairs...

Answer (score 6):

Apache Wink has [OrderedJSONObject](http://wink.apache.org/documentation/1.2.1/api/org/apache/wink/json4j/OrderedJSONObject.html). It keeps the order while parsing the String.

Answer (score 4):

Just stumbled upon the same problem, I believe the final solution used by the author consisted in using a custom ContainerFactory:

```
public static Values parseJSONToMap(String msgData) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    ContainerFactory containerFactory = new ContainerFactory(){
        @Override
        public Map createObjectContainer() {
            return new LinkedHashMap();
        }

        @Override
        public List creatArrayContainer() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    try {
        return (Map<String,Object>)parser.parse(msgData, containerFactory);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        log.warn("Exception parsing JSON string {}", msgData, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

see 
http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.html#parse(java.io.Reader,org.json.simple.parser.ContainerFactory)

Comment: really very good and practical solution. How about writing method local anonymous inner class for containerFactory?

Answer (score 2):

In the real world, an application will almost always have java bean or domain that is to be serialized/de-serialized to/from JSON. Its already mentioned that JSON Object specification does not guarantee order and any manipulation to that behavior does not justify the requirement. 
I had the same scenario in my application where I needed to preserve order just for the sack of readability purpose. I used standard jackson way to serialize my java bean to JSON:

```
Object object = getObject();  //the source java bean that needs conversion
String jsonString = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
```

In order to make the json with an ordered set of elements I just use JSON property annotation in the the Java bean I used for conversion. An example below:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"name","phone","city","id"})
public class SampleBean implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name:
    private String city;
    private String phone;

    //...standard getters and setters
}
```

the getObject() used above:

```
public SampleBean getObject(){
    SampleBean bean  = new SampleBean();
    bean.setId("100");
    bean.setName("SomeName");
    bean.setCity("SomeCity");
    bean.setPhone("1234567890");
    return bean;
}
```

The output shows as per Json property order annotation:

```
{
    name: "SomeName",
    phone: "1234567890",
    city: "SomeCity",
    id: 100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is solved and the question was asked long time ago, but as I'm dealing with a similar problem, I would like to give a totally different approach to this:

For arrays it says "An array is an ordered collection of values." at http://www.json.org/ - but objects ("An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.") aren't ordered.

I wonder why that object is in an array - that implies an order that's not there.

```
{
"items":
[
    {
        "WR":"qwe",
        "QU":"asd",
        "QA":"end",
        "WO":"hasd",
        "NO":"qwer"
    },
]
}
```

So a solution would be to put the keys in a "real" array and add the data as objects to each key like this:

```
{
"items":
[
    {"WR": {"data": "qwe"}},
    {"QU": {"data": "asd"}},
    {"QA": {"data": "end"}},
    {"WO": {"data": "hasd"}},
    {"NO": {"data": "qwer"}}
]
}
```

So this is an approach that tries to rethink the original modelling and its intent. But I haven't tested (and I wonder) if all involved tools would preserve the order of that original JSON array.

Comment: this doesn't let me make a lookup on the key.

Comment: Then what do you want - a hash or something ordered!? If you want to combine both, then create both and have one of those structures index the other one.... otherwise this seems to be more of a design problem, or mixing interests.

Comment: it's not about mixing interests, it is a fairly plausible use case, which in languages like Java is handled by constructs like LinkedHashMap, an ordered map which preserves the insertion order. Then what do I want, I want both to be able to iterate on the keys in the defined order and make a quick lookup on the keys as well. I think the answer by @Robotic Pants would work pretty much, although it is a bit hackish.

Comment: That's true, mickeymoon, I was about to say that! But in JSON this doesn't exist, does it? Then you would have to involve languages / mechanisms, that do provide you with such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) keeps orders for elements while reading json.

```
String json = "{\n"
      + "    \"items\":\n"
      + "    [\n"
      + "        {\n"
      + "            \"WR\":\"qwe\",\n"
      + "            \"QU\":\"asd\",\n"
      + "            \"QA\":\"end\",\n"
      + "            \"WO\":\"hasd\",\n"
      + "            \"NO\":\"qwer\"\n"
      + "        }\n"
      + "    ]\n"
      + "}";
System.out.println(U.fromJson(json));

// {items=[{WR=qwe, QU=asd, QA=end, WO=hasd, NO=qwer}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

patchFor(answer @gary) :

```
$ git diff JSONObject.java                                                         
diff --git a/JSONObject.java b/JSONObject.java
index e28c9cd..e12b7a0 100755
--- a/JSONObject.java
+++ b/JSONObject.java
@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@ import java.lang.reflect.Method;
 import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
 import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.Enumeration;
-import java.util.HashMap;
+import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import java.util.Map;
@@ -152,7 +152,9 @@ public class JSONObject {
      * Construct an empty JSONObject.
      */
     public JSONObject() {
-        this.map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
+//      this.map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
+        // I want to keep order of the given data:
+        this.map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
     }

     /**
@@ -243,7 +245,7 @@ public class JSONObject {
      * @throws JSONException
      */
     public JSONObject(Map<String, Object> map) {
-        this.map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
+        this.map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
         if (map != null) {
             Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();
             while (i.hasNext()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do custom ORDERED serialization and deserialization of JSON Array (This example assumes you are ordering Strings but can be applied to all types):

**Serialization**

```
JSONArray params = new JSONArray();
int paramIndex = 0;

for (String currParam : mParams)
{
    JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
    paramObject.put("index", paramIndex);
    paramObject.put("value", currParam);

    params.put(paramObject);
    ++paramIndex;
}

json.put("orderedArray", params);
```

**Deserialization**

```
JSONArray paramsJsonArray = json.optJSONArray("orderedArray");
if (null != paramsJsonArray)
{
    ArrayList<String> paramsArr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < paramsJsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject param = paramsJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (null != param)
        {
            int paramIndex = param.optInt("index", -1);
            String paramValue = param.optString("value", null);

            if (paramIndex > -1 && null != paramValue)
            {
                paramsArr.add(paramIndex, paramValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
{
    "items":
    [
        {
            "WR":"qwe",
            "QU":"asd",
            "QA":"end",
            "WO":"hasd",
            "NO":"qwer"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

add an element "itemorder"

```
{
    "items":
    [
        {
            "WR":"qwe",
            "QU":"asd",
            "QA":"end",
            "WO":"hasd",
            "NO":"qwer"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "itemorder":["WR","QU","QA","WO","NO"]
}
```

This code generates the desired output without the column title line:

```
JSONObject output = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("data");
JSONArray names = output.getJSONArray("itemOrder");
String csv = CDL.toString(names,docs);
```

Comment: This removed the header of the CSV, now I have the rows ordered but without header

Answer (score 0):

instead of using jsonObject try using CsvSchema its way easier and directly converts object to csv

```
CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(MyClass.class).withHeader();
        csvMapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(myClassList);
```

and it mentains the order id your pojo has **@JsonPropertyOrder** in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
toString(JSONArray names, JSONArray ja)
```

It Produces a comma delimited text from a JSONArray of JSONObjects using a provided list of names in the same order as json array .

Refer : https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/CDL.html#toString-org.json.JSONArray-org.json.JSONArray-

Answer (score -1):

The most safe way is probably overriding keys method that is used to generate output:

```
new JSONObject(){
  @Override
  public Iterator keys(){
    TreeSet<Object> sortedKeys = new TreeSet<Object>();
    Iterator keys = super.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
      sortedKeys.add(keys.next());
    }
    return sortedKeys.iterator();
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the stated problem.  It causes the keys to be sorted ... but the question asks for the insertion order to be preserved.

Answer (score -1):

Tested the wink solution, and working fine:

```
@Test
public void testJSONObject() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("bbb", "xxx");
    jsonObject.put("ccc", "xxx");
    jsonObject.put("aaa", "xxx");
    jsonObject.put("xxx", "xxx");
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
    assertTrue(jsonObject.toString().startsWith("{\"xxx\":"));
}

@Test
public void testWinkJSONObject() throws JSONException {
    org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONObject jsonObject = new OrderedJSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("bbb", "xxx");
    jsonObject.put("ccc", "xxx");
    jsonObject.put("aaa", "xxx");
    jsonObject.put("xxx", "xxx");
    assertEquals("{\"bbb\":\"xxx\",\"ccc\":\"xxx\",\"aaa\":\"xxx\",\"xxx\":\"xxx\"}", jsonObject.toString());
}
```

Comment: Maven dependency:  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
   <artifactId>wink-json4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Same answer as @cypressious ... posted 2 years earlier.  And the example adds no real value.