# Does the sequence of the values matter in a JSON object?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object which I have constructed within my Java program.

```
JSONObject jObj = {"AAA:aaa","BBB:bbb","CCC:ccc"}
```

I am sending this object to a server in which it expects the JSON object in the following type.

```
{"BBB:bbb", "AAA:aaa", "CCC:ccc"}
```

My question is that does the order of the JSON object really matters on the server side? If yes, how can I change the order?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Any error or exception?

Comment: The JSON RFC (RFC 4627) says that order of object members does not matter.

Comment: Note to future self when Google brings me back here: MongoDB is sensitive to the ordering of keys when checking object equality. If you have a document with _id:{key1:"foo", key2:"bar"}, you will not find it with find({_id:{key2:"bar", key1:"foo"}}).

Comment: @ahains - note to you :-)   MongoDB syntax not JSON ... strictly speaking.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> My question is that does the order of the JSON object really matters on the server side?

It **should not** matter.  According to various JSON specifications, the order of the attributes is not significant.  For example:

> "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."  (Source [json.org](http://json.org))
>
> "An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array."  (Source [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159))

Unfortunately, there are nitwits out there<sup>1</sup> who ignore that aspect of the specs, and place some significance on the order of the attributes.  (The mistake is usually made when there is a disconnect between the people specifying the APIs and those implementing them, and the people doing the specification work don't really understand JSON.)

Fortunately, the chances are that whoever designed / implemented the server didn't make that mistake.  Most Java JSON parsers I've come across don't preserve the attribute order when parsing ... by default<sup>2</sup>.  It would be hard to *accidentally* implement a server where the order of the JSON attributes being parsed was significant.

> If yes, how can i change the order?

With difficulty, I fear:

- You could generate the JSON by hand.
- There is at least one JSON for java implementation<sup>3</sup> that allows you to supply the `Map` object that holds a JSON object's attributes.  If you use a `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap`, it should retain the insertion order or the lexical order of the attribute keys.

---

<sup>1 - For example, the nitwits that this poor developer was working for ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515863/139985</sup>

<sup>2 - RFC 7159 also says this: "JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling software.  *Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be affected by these differences.*".  By my reading, this recommends that JSON libraries *should* hide any order of the pairs from application code.</sup>

<sup>3 - JSON-simple : https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/.  There could be others too.</sup>

Comment: "There are nitwits out there" indeed. I'm here looking at code that parses JSON with .split(",") and then substring().

Comment: You could add a JSON attribute listing the order of the JSON attributes in the order-managing data structure the JSON data is de-serialized into. Lots of coding fun and adding unit tests.

Comment: Yea, you could.  But a more direct way representation is an JSON array of objects (or arrays) where each object (or array) represents an name / value pair.

Comment: The unordered structure  is  one of the worst mistakes in the JSON spec because in recursive structures it makes it expensive to impossible to implement efficient stream oriented data access.

Comment: Interesting you say that. The order of keys in YAML is not significant either. So, perhaps people who need richer semantics from a serialization format should be looking for a different format?

Comment: Regardless of the intention of the spec, order preservation is highly desirable for source code diffs of user visible data like configuration files, as tools that arbitrarily reorder the keys are a nightmare to diff in code reviews (and thus we avoid such tools :b, and no, we're not nitwits).

Comment: Regardless of the "desirability" of order preservation, the spec doesn't require it and JSON (and YAML) implementations *typically don't*.  The nitwits are the people that assume that JSON (and YAML) will be ordered ... and then whinge when they design an API, data format, etc *assuming* that this is so ... and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

*IMHO* **not possible**.

[JSON docs](http://json.org/) says

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

So  the way is getting the values in required order,rather than ordering `json`

Answer (score 2):

You could use list assuming your server can accept it:

```
{"list": [ {"AAA":"aaa"},{"BBB":"bbb"},{"CCC":"ccc"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers rightly point out that the order should not matter. There are circumstances were the order may matter in a specific implementation that misunderstands the unordered nature of JSON.

For example say you want take a hash of the JSON string and store the hash for comparison against future hashes. The hash would be different if the order of the fields in the JSON string is not the same the next time you create the hash (even thought the data in the JSON string is the same).

This can happen if you're working with an API or a deserializer that returns JSON strings, with the fields in an inconsistent order.

This question more thoroughly discusses that issue and provides solutions to getting a consistent order [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Answer (score -4):

The order of fields in a JSON object actually can matter. It depends on the serializer you are using. For example, when you serialize an inherited object you will get an extra JSON field called type=''. When you deserialize it the type field must come before any other JSON Field, otherwise it takes on the type of the parent.

Comment: you are describing a bug

Comment: I think if he mentioned where this happens (which serializer?), that would have been a valid answer. Bug or not, when one is trying to create a real life application, the truth in practice is more important than the claims on paper.