# Splitting a 20 objects of Json-Array into spearte single array json files?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to split the Json data from a file.my file contains a Json array contains 20 objects in it.I want those 20 objects into 20 different files.My code works and creates files & I want to save them in a different String objects too,data in the files is jumbling.Confused how to split in correct way!
my problem:

1) My json formate in the file.
    [image]
json formate I’m getting after splitting and writing to a file[image]

My code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.*;

public class JsonSpilt {





private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;

public static void flushFile(List<Object> objects, int d) throws Exception {
    try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/home/system5/Music/tweet-" + d
        + ".json");
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(objects);
        jsonArray.write(writer);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int outputIndex = 0;
    try (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("/home/system5/Videos/tweet.json"))) {
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(input);
        if (tokener.nextClean() != '[') {
            throw tokener.syntaxError("Expected start of JSON array");
        }
        List<Object> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        while (tokener.nextClean() != ']') {

            tokener.back();

            jsonObjects.add(tokener.nextValue());

            if (jsonObjects.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
                flushFile(jsonObjects, outputIndex);
                jsonObjects.clear();
                outputIndex++;
            }

            if (tokener.nextClean() != ',') {
                tokener.back();
            }
        }
        if (!jsonObjects.isEmpty()) {
            flushFile(jsonObjects, outputIndex);
        }
        // Verify that end of input is reached.
        if (tokener.nextClean() != 0) {
            throw tokener.syntaxError("Expected end of document");
        }
    }

}}
```

sample input contains two objects in an json array.

```
[{"created_at":"Thu Jan 07 11:14:54 +0000 2016","id":685057015547220000,"id_str":"685057015547219968","text":"RT @makeinindia: Calling all techies! Collaborate, brainstorm &amp; solve urban design problems at Hackathon 2016 #MakeInIndia Week https://t.c…","source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3479265073,"id_str":"3479265073","name":"dilip bobby","screen_name":"heymailme143","location":"","description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":10,"friends_count":35,"listed_count":3,"created_at":"Mon Sep 07 07:11:18 +0000 2015","favourites_count":1,"utc_offset":-28800,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":309,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":true,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Dec 20 12:47:16 +0000 2015","id":678557275829592000,"id_str":"678557275829592064","text":"Calling all techies! Collaborate, brainstorm &amp; solve urban design problems at Hackathon 2016 #MakeInIndia Week https://t.co/ojP9Ih4p2Z","source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2785480981,"id_str":"2785480981","name":"Make in India","screen_name":"makeinindia","location":"","description":"To register for Make in India Week, click here https://t.co/unsIaezqK6","url":"http://t.co/ZBCKavarN4","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http://t.co/ZBCKavarN4","expanded_url":"http://www.makeinindia.com","display_url":"makeinindia.com","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/unsIaezqK6","expanded_url":"http://www.makeinindia.com/mumbai-week","display_url":"makeinindia.com/mumbai-week","indices":[47,70]}]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":866474,"friends_count":35,"listed_count":924,"created_at":"Tue Sep 02 07:31:24 +0000 2014","favourites_count":16,"utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":true,"verified":true,"statuses_count":4869,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"FFFFFF","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/514373412588765184/jQwP6ERL_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/514373412588765184/jQwP6ERL_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2785480981/1450423946","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":false,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":1624,"favorite_count":3168,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"MakeInIndia","indices":[97,109]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[],"media":[{"id":678556556489658400,"id_str":"678556556489658369","indices":[115,138],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","url":"https://t.co/ojP9Ih4p2Z","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/ojP9Ih4p2Z","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/makeinindia/status/678557275829592064/photo/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":800,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":340,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":600,"h":600,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":678556556489658400,"id_str":"678556556489658369","indices":[115,138],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","url":"https://t.co/ojP9Ih4p2Z","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/ojP9Ih4p2Z","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/makeinindia/status/678557275829592064/photo/1","type":"animated_gif","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":800,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":340,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":600,"h":600,"resize":"fit"}},"video_info":{"aspect_ratio":[1,1],"variants":[{"bitrate":0,"content_type":"video/mp4","url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.mp4"}]}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":true,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":1624,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"MakeInIndia","indices":[114,126]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"makeinindia","name":"Make in India","id":2785480981,"id_str":"2785480981","indices":[3,15]}],"urls":[],"media":[{"id":678556556489658400,"id_str":"678556556489658369","indices":[143,144],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","url":"https://t.co/ojP9Ih4p2Z","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/ojP9Ih4p2Z","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/makeinindia/status/678557275829592064/photo/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":800,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":340,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":600,"h":600,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":678557275829592000,"source_status_id_str":"678557275829592064","source_user_id":2785480981,"source_user_id_str":"2785480981"}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":678556556489658400,"id_str":"678556556489658369","indices":[143,144],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.png","url":"https://t.co/ojP9Ih4p2Z","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/ojP9Ih4p2Z","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/makeinindia/status/678557275829592064/photo/1","type":"animated_gif","sizes":{"large":{"w":800,"h":800,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":340,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":600,"h":600,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":678557275829592000,"source_status_id_str":"678557275829592064","source_user_id":2785480981,"source_user_id_str":"2785480981","video_info":{"aspect_ratio":[1,1],"variants":[{"bitrate":0,"content_type":"video/mp4","url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/CWq3l82UEAEjnrV.mp4"}]}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":true,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},{"created_at":"Thu Jan 07 11:14:23 +0000 2016","id":685056883325972500,"id_str":"685056883325972480","text":"RT @IntelIndia: Grammy winning composer @arrahman uses Intel Curie to turn fingertips into guitars at #CES https://t.co/5NJ3nWofyi https://…","source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3479265073,"id_str":"3479265073","name":"dilip bobby","screen_name":"heymailme143","location":"","description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":10,"friends_count":35,"listed_count":3,"created_at":"Mon Sep 07 07:11:18 +0000 2015","favourites_count":1,"utc_offset":-28800,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":309,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":true,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Wed Jan 06 11:23:57 +0000 2016","id":684696902030475300,"id_str":"684696902030475265","text":"Grammy winning composer @arrahman uses Intel Curie to turn fingertips into guitars at #CES https://t.co/5NJ3nWofyi https://t.co/HWyeANow85","source":"<a href=\"http://www.sprinklr.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Sprinklr</a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":45800443,"id_str":"45800443","name":"Intel India","screen_name":"IntelIndia","location":"India","description":"Intel India’s official Twitter handle – For technologies and devices that enrich people's lives;   House Rules: https://t.co/k0OmxmHmeO","url":"http://t.co/BnWL5Xl2Kp","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http://t.co/BnWL5Xl2Kp","expanded_url":"http://www.intel.in","display_url":"intel.in","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/k0OmxmHmeO","expanded_url":"https://tr.im/IoBoX","display_url":"tr.im/IoBoX","indices":[112,135]}]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":77465,"friends_count":549,"listed_count":311,"created_at":"Tue Jun 09 09:13:21 +0000 2009","favourites_count":3321,"utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":true,"verified":true,"statuses_count":12901,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"FFFFFF","profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000172020428/8hBrBebn.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000172020428/8hBrBebn.jpeg","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/685423865598619652/Cqe40-1O_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/685423865598619652/Cqe40-1O_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/45800443/1438925471","profile_link_color":"0070C5","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"86C6E3","profile_text_color":"444444","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":1822,"favorite_count":2653,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"CES","indices":[86,90]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"arrahman","name":"A.R.Rahman","id":19895282,"id_str":"19895282","indices":[24,33]}],"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/5NJ3nWofyi","expanded_url":"http://www.intel.sg/ces","display_url":"intel.sg/ces","indices":[91,114]}],"media":[{"id":684696901934006300,"id_str":"684696901934006272","indices":[115,138],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","url":"https://t.co/HWyeANow85","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/HWyeANow85","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/IntelIndia/status/684696902030475265/photo/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":191,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":684696901934006300,"id_str":"684696901934006272","indices":[115,138],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","url":"https://t.co/HWyeANow85","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/HWyeANow85","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/IntelIndia/status/684696902030475265/photo/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":191,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":true,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":1822,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"CES","indices":[102,106]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"IntelIndia","name":"Intel India","id":45800443,"id_str":"45800443","indices":[3,14]},{"screen_name":"arrahman","name":"A.R.Rahman","id":19895282,"id_str":"19895282","indices":[40,49]}],"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/5NJ3nWofyi","expanded_url":"http://www.intel.sg/ces","display_url":"intel.sg/ces","indices":[107,130]}],"media":[{"id":684696901934006300,"id_str":"684696901934006272","indices":[139,140],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","url":"https://t.co/HWyeANow85","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/HWyeANow85","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/IntelIndia/status/684696902030475265/photo/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":191,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":684696902030475300,"source_status_id_str":"684696902030475265","source_user_id":45800443,"source_user_id_str":"45800443"}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":684696901934006300,"id_str":"684696901934006272","indices":[139,140],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYCINGKWQAAtt6z.jpg","url":"https://t.co/HWyeANow85","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/HWyeANow85","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/IntelIndia/status/684696902030475265/photo/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":340,"h":191,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":599,"h":337,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":684696902030475300,"source_status_id_str":"684696902030475265","source_user_id":45800443,"source_user_id_str":"45800443"}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":true,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"}]
```

Comment: I'm not great with JSON in files, but loop through the array with a for-loop, and in the loop, you can get each object. Such as `JSONObject obj = input.getJSONObject(i);` That's how you separate them. Then you would write that into a file.

Comment: Thank you! I will work with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshots, everything looks fine to me. If you're worried about the sequence of the value inside the JSON Object, then you need not to worry. Refer the below link for the same.
[Does the sequence of the values matter in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870416/does-the-sequence-of-the-values-matter-in-a-json-object)

Comment: Thank you ! but cant we get them in order ?

Comment: @DilipBobby: Could you please explain a bit, why the ordering is important? As you can later fetch the objects by their key only.

Comment: Just to have any idea that's it.For now I'm not worried about the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems overcomplicated... And it's not clear how do you want to separate objects? 20 to 20 files.. is it one object per file? You can do it much easier like this, than:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "tweets.json";
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"))) {
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(reader);
            JSONArray a = new JSONArray(tokener);

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
                flushFile((JSONObject) a.get(i), i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void flushFile(JSONObject obj, int d) throws Exception {
        try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/home/dzmitry/downloads/so-test/tweet-" + d + ".json");
             Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")) {
            obj.write(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  ! I want each object in the separate file. e.g:array contains 20 obj I need those 20 in 20 separate files.Even my code looks like complicated one it works as same as yours ! but I want them in order.

Comment: Isn't my code doing what you want? What else isn't working?

Comment: got small error but I cleared that  @Dzmitry Paulenka

Comment: :only one object is written in all the 20 files ! I'm not getting the 20 different files.

Comment: Oops, I've accidentally used `a.get(0)` instead of `a.get(i)`. Edited an answer.