# How to sort objects in a field by their value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

If I have a document like this

```
{
    "_id" : "word",
    "nextWords" : {
        "x" : 3,
        "y" : 2,
        "z" : 1,
        "h" : 1,
        "n" : 10
    }
}
```

and I want to return the objects in "nextWords" sorted in a descending order.

Can I do that either in MongoDB Shell or Java?

Edit: I want "nextWords" sorted in a descending order according to its value, so the expected output is:

```
{
    "n" : 10
    "x" : 3,
    "y" : 2,
    "z" : 1,
    "h" : 1,
}
```

Comment: {
  $push: {
     <field>: {
       $each: [ <value1>, <value2>, ... ],
       $sort: <sort specification>
     }
  }
}

Comment: Please could you elaborate more? where should I pass this? and if it is an update operation I want it to be applied for the whole document and I think that would be hard to write

Comment: In short: you can not with this data model. The order in which fields are returned is simply arbitrary. You need to do the sort programmatically in your code.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, how do you think I can return "nextWords" in a data structure in Java and then sort it by its value? is it doable in this model?

Comment: You can sort an array, but not a set of fields.  They have no order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the sequence of the values matter in a JSON object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870416/does-the-sequence-of-the-values-matter-in-a-json-object)

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, I edited my question and I hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects have no order.  From [the specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) section 4.3.3:

> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which
>   contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a
>   method.

You cannot rely on the order of a field, it isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

you could instead do it as follows

{ "_id" : "word", "nextWords" : [ {"word" : "x","count" : 3 },.... ] }

use this map reduce:

```
String map = "function() { for(i in this.nextWords)emit(i.word,i.count) }

String reduce = "function(key,value){return (value);}";
```

run it in java:

```
MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand(collection, map, reduce, null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null);

MapReduceOutput out = collection.mapReduce(cmd);

for (DBObject o : out.results()) {
       // here put them in an array 
    }
```

//sort the array

Comment: The order of the emitted values may or may not be in order. And your map reduce does not change this fact. Furthermore, with that structure, the map/reduce is totally unneeded, as `db.words.aggregate({$unwind:"$nextWords"},{$sort:{"$nextWord.count":-1}},{$group:{_id:"$word",sorted:{$push:"$nextWord"}}})` would do the same, plus the iteration you put into the code.

Comment: I wrote it that way because using mongodb's api  in java  makes it hard to access nested sub documents. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: You can do aggregations with the Java driver. ;) And I doubt that you need a m/r to access subdocs.