# Move an element at the beginning of an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have array format like this

```js
newresponse = [{
  data: {
    Bal Vivah: 1
    Type: 0
    districts: "East District"
  },
  data: {
    Bal Vivah: 1
    Type: 0
    districts: "West District"
  },
  data: {
    Bal Vivah: 1
    Type: 0
    districts: "North District"
  }
}]
```

and the required format is

```js
newresponse = [{
  data: {
    districts: "East District"
    Bal Vivah: 1
    Type: 0
  },
  data: {
    districts: "West District"
    Bal Vivah: 1
    Type: 0
  },
  data: {
    districts: "North District"
    Bal Vivah: 1
    Type: 0
  }
}]
```

here I need the value of the districts at the beginning of the array, other then districts all key and values will be dynamic, hence districts should be on the top of the array.

Comment: Why do you wants this?

Comment: need to display data on the data-table and the first column should be districts

Comment: Order of the properties does not matter in JSON. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870531/4469840

Comment: in table you can bind value order you want using {{}} interpolation

Comment: but i need the district at the top because I have to display complain reports based on district, and complain are bal vivha, type etc.. and the array format which has district on the bottom shows on data table at the end

Comment: i cannot bind the value using interpolation because my data is dynamic ,     <th class="custom-header-col" *ngFor="let column of columns">
                {{column}}
              </th>

Comment: <td class="custom-body-col" *ngFor='let column of columns'>{{data.data[column]| json}}</td>

Comment: Your response is **invalid**! You **cannot** have multiple properties with the same `key`. There are 3 properties named `data`  in your JSON. I think you should redefine the way you produce the response.

Comment: the data is valid, i just want the district key at the top

Comment: @vinuta How can it be **valid** if there are multiple values with same key? Which data do you expect to get with `newresponse[0]['data']`?

Comment: Beside the point mentioned by @Adhyatmik I will also like to metion that `Bal Vivah: 1` this key name is invalid and it may not work

Answer (score 0):

The object that you have posted is not a valid object. The `data` property is duplicate. If the object was valid, and you are trying to display the details as a `key-value` pair, you can use `keyvalue` pipe (https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#keyvaluepipe). You can pass a comparator function which you can code to give you the districts as the first value.

Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyvalue-comparator

Comment: i will try this