# Java add json key value at the beginning

Tags: java, json

I have a json string **jsonstring** that looks like this

```
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "Name": "Appli",
      "ID": "519"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dash",
      "ID": "602"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I add a key value pair in front of Users like so:

```
{
  "Department":"Accounting", 
  "Users": [
    {
      "Name": "Appli",
      "ID": "519"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dash",
      "ID": "602"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: according to spec the sequence should not matter. "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870416/does-the-sequence-of-the-values-matter-in-a-json-object

Comment: Use a JSON library, then parse the JSON text, add the extra key/value pair, and regenerate JSON text. Exactly how to do it depends entirely on which JSON library you choose.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try format String to JSONObject , then use JSONObject  set key value

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");
}catch (JSONException err){
     Log.d("Error", err.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To address this specific case you may identify the pattern and use `String.replaceAll` method like this:

```
String usersWithDepartment = jsonstring.replaceAll(
    "(\"Users\":\\s*\\[)", // find a pattern for "Users" element
    "\"Department\": \"Accounting\",\n  $1" // add a prefix and keep the group $1 as is
);
System.out.println(usersWithDepartment);
```

This is a quick fix and of course more appropriate approach is to use some JSON processing library as mentioned in the comments.

**update**

If several occurrences of `\"Users\"` array are possible in the input string and you need to add the prefix only to the first occurrence, the regexp should be changed to:

```
String usersWithDepartment = jsonstring.replaceAll(
    "(?s)(\"Users\":\\s*\\[.*$)", // grab entire string, enable multiline selection
    "\"Department\": \"Accounting\",\n  $1" // add prefix
);
```