# In Rest Assured, arrange the order of payload

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have written code for Rest Assured API to automate, I've created the payload using JSONObject but the payload is not ordered because of which I am getting an error. Below is how my payload should look like

```
{
    "Student": "Primary",
    "class": "First",
    "segments": [{
            "Subject": "Science",
            "Marks": "50"

        },
        {

            "Subject": "History",
            "Marks": "50"
        }
    ],
    "Fee": "Paid",
    "Roll no": "20"
}
```

but the payload generated by the object mapper is as below

```
 {
    "Student": "Primary",
    "class": "First",
    "Fee": "Paid",
    "Roll no": "20",

    "segments": [{
            "Subject": "Science",
            "Marks": "50"

        },
        {

            "Subject": "History",
            "Marks": "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the code written in Java

```
JSONObject requestParam = new JSONObject();
JSONArray requestParamArray = new JSONArray();

requestParam.put("Student", strStud);
requestParam.put("class", strClass);

Map searchReqMap1 = new LinkedHashMap(3);
searchReqMap1.put("Subject", strsubject);
searchReqMap1.put("mark", strmark);

Map searchReqMap2 = new LinkedHashMap(3);
searchReqMap2.put("Subject", strsubject);
searchReqMap2.put("mark", strmark);

requestParamArray.add(searchReqMap1);
requestParamArray.add(searchReqMap2);

requestParam.put("segments", requestParamArray);
requestParam.put("fee", strfee);
requestParam.put("rollno", strrollno);
return requestParam.toJSONString();
```

` Input data is read from excel

Comment: JSONObject is unordered, Use LinkedHashMap is you want it ordered

Answer (score 0):

Could you give some error log to let us know why you think **"but the payload is not ordered because of which I am getting an error."**

As far as I know, order of JSON object members does not matter. See this: [Does the sequence of the values matter in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870416/does-the-sequence-of-the-values-matter-in-a-json-object)

Your code looks very good. Only this sentence `new LinkedHashMap(3)`, I think maybe it should be `new LinkedHashMap(2)`.

So please show more info, I will edit this answer later.