# JavaScript object order when key is timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

JavaScript has set of rules when it comes to order object properties. There is strange example for me.

When timestamp in **milliseconds** is used as object property key, then ordering **doesn't work**.

When timestamp in **seconds** is used as object property key, then ordering **works**.

```js
var objS = {
    1600333200: 'a',
    1600419600: 'b',
    1600338600: 'c'
};
console.log('seconds', JSON.stringify(objS));


var objMs = {
    1600333200000: 'a',
    1600419600000: 'b',
    1600338600000: 'c'
};
console.log('milliseconds', JSON.stringify(objMs));
```

Are there any explanation?

Comment: I think numeric keys up ro 2^32 (or 2^31?) come out ordered ... but ... I'd have to look if that's in some specification - I've always been of the opinion that key order is not guaranteed at all - but specs change

Comment: AFAIK, The ordering of keys in JS object aren't guaranteed for any type. I strongly suggest you do not rely on them for any kind of logic.

Comment: I just read that the order should be numeric for any key that can be an integer up to 2^53 ... but clearly that is wrong

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari - there has been a change in ES6 - just hunting it down (that's what google is for)

Comment: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari - the spec says `"integer indices in ascending numeric, then strings in property creation order, then symbols in property creation order"` - so, there is a specified order ... just the integer thing seems whack

Comment: a quick test ... integer means number up to `2^32` after that they are not considered numeric - so become "strings in creation order"

Comment: The millisecond keys should still be treated as integers, `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER < 1600333200000 // false`

Comment: Use `Array` instead, and `sort`.
`Object` does NOT guarantee order.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the order of properties in an object (think of a map) is almost never guaranteed; but since the introduction of [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), the [predictability of property order](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/) has been introduced. But… the [order of keys](https://medium.com/@ty0h/preserving-json-object-keys-order-in-javascript-python-and-go-language-170eaae0de03#5b82) is still not guaranteed according to the [JSON spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870531/1762224).

You could write your own serialization function to sort the keys numerically.

```js
const serialize = obj =>
  `{${Object.keys(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))
    .map(key => `"${key}":${JSON.stringify(obj[key])}`).join(',')}}`;

var objMs = {
  1600338600000: 'c',
  1600333200000: 'a',
  1600419600000: 'b',
};

console.log('milliseconds', serialize(objMs));
```

#### Output

```
milliseconds {"1600333200000":"a","1600338600000":"c","1600419600000":"b"}
```

Comment: Sure, that is good solution. But I just want to understand what is issue.

Comment: @poletn23 I added some links.