# How to send a Json string in the correct order?

Tags: c++, json, c++17, nlohmann-json

Using this line of code:

```cpp
nlohmann::json msg_j = "{\"H\":\"1\",\"N\":3,\"D1\":3,\"D2\":150}"_json; 
std::string s = msg_j.dump();
```

I get as a result s:

```json
{"D1":3,"D2":150,"H":"1","N":3}
```

Which is not in the desired order:

```json
{"H":"1","N":3,"D1":3,"D2":150}
```

Please tell me how to get it, so I can finally solve my request for this post.

As JSON library for C++, I use `nlohmann::json`.

Comment: I don't think key/value pairs in JSON are supposed to be ordered. The receiving side should not care about the ordering. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870416/does-the-sequence-of-the-values-matter-in-a-json-object.

Comment: Actually the order is important for me as this message has to be sent to a server via tcp/ip.

Comment: Are you sure the server cares about the order?

Comment: See [`nlohmann::ordered_json`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/ordered_json/).  There is no corresponding user-defined literal type though, so you'll have to `parse` the string.

Comment: The server shouldn't care about the order either. `nlohmann::json` uses a `std::map` for its `ObjectType` by default. So the values will be ordered.

Comment: A version of json for Arduino UNO is used on the server...
What makes me angry that the same program written in python works fine, while this one in C++ fails :(

Comment: Nobody should care about the order of the values, as the JSON spec says: "*The JSON syntax does not impose any restrictions on the strings used as names, does not require that name strings be unique, and **does not assign any significance to the ordering of name/value pairs**.*"

Comment: You are all right. May I ask if you can help me convert the Python program into C++, perhaps by opening a new post ? I'm literally going crazy, I've been trying and trying for days, I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: @giorgio Feel free to post specific questions about parts you're having trouble with.  "Help me convert this python program to C++" would probably get closed as too broad.  "I'm converting this python program to C++ and don't understand why this part doesn't work" is much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Miles Budnek

Comment: @giorgio: Does this help. https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example6.md