# Why @ResponseBody returns sorted LinkedHashMap as not sorted?

Tags: java, json, sorting, spring-mvc, linkedhashmap

Here is SpringMVC Controller code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCityList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody LinkedHashMap<String, String> getCityList(@RequestParam(value = "countryCode") String countryCode, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    //gets ordered city list of country  [sorted by city name]
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> cityList = uiOperationsService.getCityList(countryCode); 

    for (String s : cityList.values()) {
        System.out.println(s); //prints sorted list  [sorted by name]
    }
    return cityList;
}
```

Here is ajax call:

```
function fillCityList(countryCode) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/getCityList',
            data: {countryCode:countryCode},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#city').html("<option value=''>-- SELECT --</option>" );
            }
        }).done(function (data) {

            console.log(data); // UNSORTED JSON STRING  [Actually sorted by key... not by city name]

        })
    }
```

Sorted LinkedHashMap returns as unsorted JSON object from getCityList method. Why order is changed during return process ? 
Is LinkedHashMap converted to HashMap because of ResponseBody annotation? 
I can convert my sorted object to json string via Gson library and return json string from my getCityList method but i don't like this solution. What can i do to provide javascript callback method with sorted list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're expecting a JSON object's entries to have the same order as the LinkedHashMap entries. That won't happen, because JavaScript object keys have no intrinsic order. They're just like Java HashMaps.

If you need a JavaScript data structure that maintains an order, you should use an array, not an object. Return a sorted `List<City>` from your method, where `City` has a key and a value.

Comment: I don't prefer List for my methods because my jstl serialization uses LinkedHashMap: `<form:options items="${cityList}"></form:options>`. But I think unwillingly i should make exception and convert LinkedHashMap to List in methods that returns response to ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to send sorted data then pass `List` of Your object or City as `List<City>` which have sorted data.

I have also face same problem when I have used `HashMap` in my application, it doesn't guarantee that it will receive in `same order in which we add them`. We have to access it via it's key.

so it's better to use `List` instead of `LinkedHashMap`.

Most implementations of `JSON` make no effort to preserve the order of an object's `name/value` pairs, since it is `(by definition)` not significant.

Comment: Are you sure about LinkedHasMap insertion order ? Java docs suggests otherwise http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: @Shailendra : see http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-vs-treemap-vs#highlighter_525587 with example.

Comment: What do you mean by _implementations of JSON_? JSON is a format.

Comment: Yes it is a format, I am just talking about that the order is not preserve in the JSON when we use it. look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv

Comment: @user3145373 : the article you mentions too states "LinkedHashMap preserves the insertion order" just like what javadocs states

Comment: I am not using HashMap. LinkedHashMap preserves order, your case is not related with mine.

Comment: @MustafaYüceel : I know that, I am just telling you about what I  have faced. Otherwise whatever details I have that I have posted.