# Convert json string to json object without changing the keys order

Tags: android, json

I have a  json string as shown below

```
{
"college": {
    "id": "RPD4007",
    "address": "#302, 1 st cross"
},
"deparment": {
    "department1": {
        "name": {
            "maths": {
                "chapter": 1,
                "name": "algebra",
                "module_id": "01"
            },
            "electronics": {
                "chapter": 1,
                "name": "ec",
                "module_id": "01"
            }
        }
    },
    "department2": {
        "name": {
            "english": {
                "chapter": 2,
                "name": "algebra",
                "module_id": "02"
            },
            "electrical": {
                "chapter": 2,
                "name": "algebra",
                "module_id": "02"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have tried to convert this json sring to json object ,

```
string json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
jObj = new JSONObject(json_string);//json object
JSONObject object = jobj.getJSONObject("college");
```

But the jobj output I got is in reverse order of json string .Like below,

```
{
"college": {
    "id": "RPD4007",
    "address": "#302, 1 st cross"
},
"deparment": {
    "department2": {
        "name": {
            "electrical": {
                "chapter": 2,
                "name": "algebra",
                "module_id": "02"
            },
            "english": {
                "chapter": 2,
                "name": "algebra",
                "module_id": "02"
            }
        }
    },
    "department1": {
        "name": {
            "electronics": {
                "chapter": 1,
                "name": "ec",
                "module_id": "01"
            },
            "maths": {
                "chapter": 1,
                "name": "algebra",
                "module_id": "01"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

How to get it in same order as it is?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515863/3514144

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making jsonObject for two times.
Just do something like this
you have String that contains JSON DATA
Make an object for that which you did

```
string json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
jObj = new JSONObject(json_string);//json object
```

then make a loop to get the object inside that object using

```
 String college = jobj.getString("college");
```

Answer (score -1):

The answers here: [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/4201441)

As a consequence, JSON libraries are free to rearrange the order of the elements as they see fit. This is not a bug.