# Keys getting sorted automatically in JSON object

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON object in which I have some arrays with keys:

```
{  
  "body":{  
    "menus":{  
      "":[  
        {  
          "name":"home",
          "label":"Home",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_global_search",
          "label":"Search",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        }
      ],
      "Favorites":[  
        {  
          "name":"core_mini_messages",
          "label":"Messages",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_mini_notification",
          "label":"Notifications",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_mini_friend_request",
          "label":"Friend Requests",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_user",
          "label":"Members",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_album",
          "label":"Albums",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_video",
          "label":"Videos",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_blog",
          "label":"Blogs",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_classified",
          "label":"Classifieds",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_group",
          "label":"Groups",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_event",
          "label":"Events",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"core_main_music",
          "label":"Music",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        }
      ],
      "Account Settings":[  
        {  
          "name":"user_settings",
          "label":"Settings",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"contact_us",
          "label":"Contact Us",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"privacy_policy",
          "label":"Privacy Policy",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        },
        {  
          "name":"terms_of_service",
          "label":"Terms Of Service",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        }
      ],
      "Help & Settings":[  
        {  
          "name":"signout",
          "label":"Sign Out",
          "headerLabel":"",
          "icon":"",
          "url":""
        }
      ]
    },
    "languages":{  
      "default":"en",
      "languages":{  
        "en":"English"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to iterate over the elements in the same order that they are coming from server, but the keys change their order automatically alphabetical.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem would be to send another object through that has a key=>value association with numbers as the key and the menu items as the values, e.g.

```
{1:"", 2:"Favorites", 3:"Account Settings", 4:"Help & Settings"}
```

I would then iterate through this object and use it to retrieve the menus from the original object in the right order.

Comment: `{1:"", 2:"Favorites", 3:"Account Settings", 4:"Help & Settings"}` is [not a valid json](http://bit.ly/1NroA4W) ...

Comment: It's only an example, to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at previous answers there seem to be two ways to solve the problem:

1. Restructure your data, change menues to look like this:

   ```
   {
     "menues": [
                {"": ... },
                {"Favorites": ... },
                ...]}
   ```
2. Change your JSONObject.java file it uses a HashMap but a LinkedHashMap should preserve the order. This will only work in systems that use your JSONObject.java though.

   ```
   //this.map = new HashMap();
   this.map = new LinkedHashMap();
   ```

Both solution I got from there: [Keep the order of the JSON keys during JSON conversion to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv) for better explanations.