# Format a String in Json style

Tags: java, json

I extracted a huge String from a webpage and want to style/formatting this in Json style. The extracted String was originally a Json format but now after extracting this is just a long String. I used JsonObj for this and the formatter does curios things, he moved text from the bottom to top changed the generally the line orders etc.

http://pastebin.com/exwwc6SY  JsonFile after Formatting

http://pastebin.com/WHXtE36G  The extracted String

And here the code

```
try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/tmp/1.txt");
        String line = ROUtils.getStringFromInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(line);
        String jsonObj = new JSONObject(line).toString(2);
        fw.write(jsonObj);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the getStringFromInputStream() method

```
public static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

### Update

I found a new issue. The JsonObj File its not equal to the original String.
I compared the number of Characters (no spaces). The original String has 96311 and the JsonObj has 92636. Can anyone give me a hint what should I do?

Comment: Apparently we need to sign up to filedropper to view the file, Could you use pastebin instead?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VfbKsQw6

Comment: @AndrewB no need to subscribe at all. But I submitted a review to add the links to pastebin. Didn't see anything wrong with the JSON file. The problem is the order of the elements?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cNZEy49z

Comment: The original String Starts whit {

    "@id":........, after the formatting he starts whit {
  "isLike":..... and the "@id" is now moved somewhere in the middle of the text. and that is just a exemple.

Comment: @RaulVasi edit your original post to add the links. The JSON specification at http://www.json.org/ says "an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs" so you can rely on json elements ordering.

Comment: Yes, that's the main issue here. When this is parsed into a  `JSONObject`, then it will internally basically be stored as a `Map<String, Whatever>`, where the properties are the *keys* of the map. The order of the map entries may be arbitrary, but from a first glance, it might be a `TreeMap`, which causes the properties to be written in alphabetical order. (EDIT: Looked it up: It seems to be a `HashMap`, so the order is arbitrary)

Comment: Also I would like to know what JSON api you are using @RaulVasi because you have a toString method with a parameter at `String jsonObj = new JSONObject(line).toString(2);`. What I know is the JSON libraries are free to rearrange the order of the elements as they want so whatever api you are using you **can't** rely on ordering.

Comment: Found it: org.json.JSONObject - http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Is the JSON available publicly? Please add a link to the JSON source in your question (if its public). That would help quickly diagnose your issue and find suitable answer.

Comment: yes, the lib is json.org and the webpage is usser-pass protected, but u can use link  http://pastebin.com/cNZEy49z , its the original text whitout formatting.

Comment: i downloaded the html page. Here the link: http://www.filedropper.com/httpsapiellinet-devhbz-nrwderesourcefrl3175693alljsonstylelong

Comment: So eventually, this could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv

Comment: Ok guys i give it up to input in the same order as he is written but the document after formatting aren't the same! Like 4000 characters are missing, whats going worn there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a JSON object.

From the JSON specification at http://www.json.org/

An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Comment: Ok, i understand now. Did u have a suggestion how can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out why i missed 4000 characters after converting.
I forgot to close the FileWriter!

```
fw.close();
```

The close() methods calls the flush() method so that the last buffered piece of the String can written down.

Thank u guys.