# Unordered data of JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json, unordered

I am using JSONObject for entering data and computing something out if it. Lets suppose i entered data in form :-

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("uuid", newImageUuid);
obj.put("type", "image");
obj.put("value", base64ImagePath);
```

For SDK version above 19 i get it in perfect order but for versions below it the order of the json reverses. Value comes first , then type, then uuid.

I have tried this way :-

```
Map obj=new LinkedHashMap();
                obj.put("uuid", newImageUuid);
                obj.put("type", "image");
                obj.put("value", base64ImagePath);
                StringWriter data = new StringWriter();
                JSONValue.writeJSONString(obj, data);
```

Data is in ordered manner and in the form in which i want but i cant make use of this data as type of it is StringWriter. But when i convert this data back into JSONObject , result will be in unordered fashion . I have tried many methods like storing in linkedhashmaps and then converting into JSONObjects but of no use. Could anyone please help to it.

Comment: hope this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv

Comment: @Sandeep :- Tried but of no value

Comment: try this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7981662/2116420](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7981662/2116420)

Comment: @Naz141 :- I have gone through that java file but there is only LinkedHashMap that have been mapped.

Comment: Can i know why you are depending on the ordered JSONObject data.

Comment: @Naz141 :- Thanks . Yup i have changed my methodology to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As JSON [official](http://json.org/) doc says:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

So `JSONObject` does't have any specific order.. Neither `Serializer` nor `Parsers` doesn't care about order of `JSONObject` key/values. Now if you really insist in keeping order you can try to convert your `Key/Value`s to Array of `Objects` composited of `Key` and `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Object does not have any order.It is a key/value pair.We can save value with the key

We can get the value by using key

If you want ordered data, you can use array,arraylist