# How to Preserve insertion Order in Simple JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json, simplejson

I have a json string that has multiple sub objects, While converting this string using

```
JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonString);
```

the insertion order is missed out in jsonObject especially **dataCollection** object.
Is there a way or any library to preserve elements order during the conversion?

**Sample Json:**

```
{
  "Id": "f4a305705b064074a0ed15531031f3d0",
  "FirstName": "Name",
  "description": "Description",
  "data": {
    "dataCollection": {
      "Location": 883000,
      "Type": "Vehicle",
      "isRegistered": true,
      "wheels": 4,
      "isPowerSteered": "yes"
    },
    "Region": "India"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep the order of the JSON keys during JSON conversion to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv)

Comment: according to this, json should be unordered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv