# How do I iterate over a dictionary created by JSON in the order of key-value pairs specified?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON that looks like the following (this example is just a toy example to illustrate the point, default iteration might work by luck).

```
{ "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3 }
```

I can load this JSON into a Python (v2.7) dictionary.

```
with open('/path/to/json/file') as f:
     json_data = json.load(f)
```

I then iterate over the key-value pairs as follows.

```
for k, v in json_data.iteritems():
     print('{}, {}'.format(k, v))
```

What is printed is the following.

```
A, 1
C, 3
B, 2
```

What I want is to be able to iterate over the items in the order that was specified in the JSON. So, my expected output should be.

```
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
```

Is there any way to read in and store the key-value pairs from JSON to a Python dictionary such that when I iterate over them, the order specified by JSON is preserved and read back in such order?

I do not have control with the producer of the JSON to store the data in an array (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv) for Java). I am wondering if there is a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) like in Java with Python that perhaps I may use with `json.load` to preserve the insertion order for reading.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In all likelihood, the order that you received the key/value pairs in JSON is arbitrarily ordered, so why would you need to maintain order as a consumer? If the API thought order was important, they would have used a list structure

Comment: No, the key-value pairs are not arbitrarily ordered; that was definitely an oversight on their end. Yes, I agree, they should have used a list structure.

Comment: @JaneWayne Do you have to use Python 2.7?

Comment: @G_M Yes, for now; but our code is branched for 3.6 compatibility too; and so any logic would have to work for both 2.7 and 3.6. But I'd love to hear the solution that is dependent on 2.7.

Comment: @JaneWayne My first thought was that dictionaries are now ordered by default in Python 3.6 so you might not need any modifications there (would need to be tested). https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/8079103

Comment: @G_M Guaranteed ordering is an implementation detail of CPython in 3.6; the language only provides the guarantee in 3.7.

Comment: The link can be correct without your summary of it being correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the json loader to build an OrderedDict:

```
import json
import collections

with open('example.json') as f:
    json_object = json.load(f,object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
```

Comment: You need to use `object_pairs_hook`, not `object_hook` (which is called on the `dict` created by the initial parsing).