# How to keep the order of org.json.JSONObject？

Tags: csv, org.json

Because I want to use the conversion CSV file function in org.json, I must use org.json.
and the csv order is the same as JSONArray, so I need a correct Order JSONArray.
I found that JSONArray order is the same as put into it, but JSONObject is order by 'a-z',
How to make the order of jsonObject the same as  when I put it.
my code is :

```html
org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("text1","111");
jsonObject.put("abc1","111");

org.json.JSONObject jsonObject2 = new org.json.JSONObject();
jsonObject2.put("text2","222");
jsonObject2.put("abc2","222");

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);

System.out.println(jsonObject);
System.out.println(jsonObject2);
System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

The result is

```
{"abc1":"111","text1":"111"}

{"text2":"222","abc2":"222"}

[{"abc1":"111","text1":"111"},{"text2":"222","abc2":"222"}]
```

but I want

```
{"text1":"111","abc1":"111"}

{"text2":"222","abc2":"222"}

[{"text1":"111","abc1":"111"},{"text2":"222","abc2":"222"}]
```

Comment: JSON objects aren't ordered to begin with. Arrays are, which is why you see that behaviour with an array. Given that you access their values by name, not position, it doesn't matter.

Comment: i want to tranfer json into csv, and the csv order is the same as JSONObect...

Comment: The JSON object *doesn't have an order*. Also you don't seem to have any CSV.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv see it, it is what i want to do.

Comment: And as the first comment and the highest-rated answer say...

Comment: Add some code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I use the alibaba.json to contains the order of JsonObject.
and Then I overwrite the org.json's CDL.toString by alibaba.json lib.

```html
package com._4paradigm.repservice.utils;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class ConvertCsv {
    public ConvertCsv() {
    }
    public static String toString(JSONArray ja) {

        JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(0);
        if (jo != null) {
            Set<String> strings = jo.keySet();
            JSONArray names = JSONArray.parseArray(JSON.toJSONString(strings));
            if (names != null) {
                return rowToString(names) + toString(names, ja);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    public static String rowToString(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size() ; ++i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(',');
            }
            Object object = jsonArray.get(i);
            if (object != null) {
                String string = object.toString();
//                System.out.println(string);
                if (string.length() > 0 && (string.indexOf(44) >= 0 || string.indexOf(10) >= 0 || string.indexOf(13) >= 0 || string.indexOf(0) >= 0 || string.charAt(0) == '"')) {
                    sb.append('"');
                    int length = string.length();

                    for(int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
                        char c = string.charAt(j);
                        if (c >= ' ' && c != '"') {
                            sb.append(c);
                        }
                    }

                    sb.append('"');
                } else {
                    sb.append(string);
                }
            }
        }

        sb.append('\n');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String toString(JSONArray names, JSONArray ja) {
        if (names != null && names.size() != 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for(int i = 0; i < ja.size(); ++i) {
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                if (jo != null) {
                    sb.append(rowToString(toJSONArray(jo, names)));
                }
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static JSONArray toJSONArray(JSONObject obj, JSONArray names)  {
        if (names != null && !names.isEmpty()) {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) {
                ja.add(obj.get(names.getString(i)));
            }

            return ja;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(new LinkedHashMap<>());
        object2.put("name","LiMing");
        object2.put("age","28");
        object2.put("gender","man");

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new LinkedHashMap<>());
        object.put("name","LiPing");
        object.put("age","26");
        object.put("gender","women");

        array.add(object);
        array.add(object2);

        String s = ConvertCsv.toString(array);

        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("E:\\hello.csv"), s);
    }
}
```