# Google Script sort JSON nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

im trying to sort a nested array before copying back to Gsheet, i was helped on a previous part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460401/google-script-json-nested-arrays-to-cell), however when i save the script i get an error "illegal Character", i have copied the script to a new sheet and it saves and works, however on my current script i can seem to save the script without that error, is there another way i can re-order that set of arrays.

I have to use my current sheet as there is a lot more code which i cannot just leave so hence i have to use my current sheet/project

my desired output is

```js
{ "1fI": "72217193", "3PCdays": 30, "2PVdays": 30 } to { "1fI": "72217193", "2PVdays": 30,"3PCdays": 30... }
```

```js
function testAPI(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mySheet');

  var response =  {"lineItems":[{"name":"advertisers/1558261/lineItems/12317016","advertiserId":"1238261","campaignId":"1233305","insertionOrderId":"13016372","lineItemId":"12317016","displayName":"All | Routes| All Users | ABC | ABC-LI1","lineItemType":"LINE_ITEM_TYPE_DISPLAY_DEFAULT","entityStatus":"ENTITY_STATUS_ACTIVE","updateTime":"2020-04-15T12:51:42.929Z","partnerCosts":[{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_THIRD_PARTY_AD_SERVER","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_CPM_FEE","feeAmount":"1000000","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER"},{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_DOUBLE_VERIFY_PREBID","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_CPM_FEE","feeAmount":"0","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_DV360"},{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_DV360_FEE","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_MEDIA_FEE","feePercentageMillis":"0","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_DV360"},{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_DEFAULT","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_MEDIA_FEE","feePercentageMillis":"0","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER"}],"flight":{"flightDateType":"LINE_ITEM_FLIGHT_DATE_TYPE_CUSTOM","dateRange":{"startDate":{"year":2020,"month":4,"day":15},"endDate":{"year":2020,"month":4,"day":30}}},"budget":{"budgetAllocationType":"LINE_ITEM_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_TYPE_UNLIMITED","budgetUnit":"BUDGET_UNIT_CURRENCY"},"pacing":{"pacingPeriod":"PACING_PERIOD_DAILY","pacingType":"PACING_TYPE_EVEN","dailyMaxMicros":"40100000"},"frequencyCap":{"timeUnit":"TIME_UNIT_DAYS","timeUnitCount":1,"maxImpressions":5},"partnerRevenueModel":{"markupType":"PARTNER_REVENUE_MODEL_MARKUP_TYPE_TOTAL_MEDIA_COST_MARKUP"},"conversionCounting":{"postViewCountPercentageMillis":"100000","floodlightActivityConfigs":[{"1fI":"7517101","3PCdays":30,"2PVdays":30},{"1fI":"7541802","3PCdays":30,"2PVdays":30},{"1fI":"7552803","3PCdays":30,"2PVdays":30},{"1fI":"7517104","3PCdays":30,"2PVdays":30}]},"bidStrategy":{"fixedBid":{"bidAmountMicros":"3610000"}},"integrationDetails":{}},{"name":"advertisers/1558261/lineItems/12317017","advertiserId":"1238261","campaignId":"1233305","insertionOrderId":"13016372","lineItemId":"12317017","displayName":"All | Routes| All Users | ABC | ABC-LI2","lineItemType":"LINE_ITEM_TYPE_DISPLAY_DEFAULT","entityStatus":"ENTITY_STATUS_ACTIVE","updateTime":"2020-04-01T16:06:19.831Z","partnerCosts":[{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_THIRD_PARTY_AD_SERVER","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_CPM_FEE","feeAmount":"1000000","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER"},{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_DOUBLE_VERIFY_PREBID","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_CPM_FEE","feeAmount":"0","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_DV360"},{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_DV360_FEE","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_MEDIA_FEE","feePercentageMillis":"0","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_DV360"},{"costType":"PARTNER_COST_TYPE_DEFAULT","feeType":"PARTNER_COST_FEE_TYPE_MEDIA_FEE","feePercentageMillis":"0","invoiceType":"PARTNER_COST_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER"}],"flight":{"flightDateType":"LINE_ITEM_FLIGHT_DATE_TYPE_CUSTOM","dateRange":{"startDate":{"year":2020,"month":4,"day":15},"endDate":{"year":2020,"month":4,"day":30}}},"budget":{"budgetAllocationType":"LINE_ITEM_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_TYPE_UNLIMITED","budgetUnit":"BUDGET_UNIT_CURRENCY"},"pacing":{"pacingPeriod":"PACING_PERIOD_DAILY","pacingType":"PACING_TYPE_EVEN","dailyMaxMicros":"26730000"},"frequencyCap":{"timeUnit":"TIME_UNIT_DAYS","timeUnitCount":1,"maxImpressions":5},"partnerRevenueModel":{"markupType":"PARTNER_REVENUE_MODEL_MARKUP_TYPE_TOTAL_MEDIA_COST_MARKUP"},"conversionCounting":{"postViewCountPercentageMillis":"100000"},"bidStrategy":{"fixedBid":{"bidAmountMicros":"3610000"}},"integrationDetails":{}}]};
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

  var LiData = data["lineItems"]; 
  var rows = [],
      data;
  for (i = 0; i < LiData.length; i++) {
      data = LiData[i];
      

  rows.push([
    data.campaignId,
    data.conversionCounting.floodlightActivityConfigs
  ]);

    }

dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length,2).setValues(rows);

}
```

Comment: did you use that same exact code when saving the script?  there's a lot of people getting the same error using the wrong type of quotes in their code because they used a word processor to copy and paste their code.  If you copy and pasted your JSON data from a table cell in docs, the wrong quotes is most likely oyur problem

Comment: yep exact same code, the weired thing is, i copied the same code to a new sheet and it was working, im not sure what settings might be different on my current project that may be causing this.

Comment: Also to note, i have to use my current project as there a lot more things that is being done apart from this API, so i cannot just use a new sheet

Comment: it should give a line number error.  keep deleting lines in your script until it stops complaining

Comment: ive tried this code in my project under a new script file, still no luck

Comment: what line number does it complain about.  find the line.  and keep editing and saving the script removing one line at a time, until it stops complaining about the illegal character.  then you've found the code that causes a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216428/discussion-between-imdad-rahman-and-user120242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you.  I've transpiled it using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=E4ew7gzgdADgrhAFgCgNoCgAEmAmBDAFzygGM8BbGPASwHMA7ASRwBotdDiSR6A3AU2ARqPAMIg49AtXq0oAMwA2IEDkV1EBAIIlpvagQCe4-vLoRMAfkwADVABIA3viKkeAoSPrjJ02QuVVdVpNHT0DYx4zWmhyPBhkfkwAXgA-W0cnAHkAIwArfl0ofilgan4IRIBKKDiEtABrFkxeAF0qlPSjGH4QeRaU5MwAIno4chzBYatbYacGgF9hgC4nXgWbTGXZ-aXlucd14ZsaiBBgAmQavJAZZGGWYaqFjevb-nvH59bN7eHh9DtADcQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.3&externalPlugins=) and added polyfills for `Object.keys` and `Object.entries`.  For some reason Google Scripts sometimes choke on code that uses newer syntax:

```
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function() {
    'use strict';
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({ toString: null }).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function(obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'function' && (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null)) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
      }

      var result = [], prop, i;

      for (prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
          result.push(prop);
        }
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
            result.push(dontEnums[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  }());
}
if (!Object.entries) {
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
        resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
}

rows.push([data.campaignId, data.conversionCounting.floodlightActivityConfigs ? "[" + data.conversionCounting.floodlightActivityConfigs.map(function (e) {
  return "{" + Object.entries(e).map(function (_ref) {
    var k = _ref[0],
        v = _ref[1];
    return typeof v == "number" ? "\"" + k + "\":" + v : "\"" + k + "\":\"" + v + "\"";
  }).sort().join(",") + "}";
}).join(",") + "]" : ""]);
```

Comment: im getting the following error now 
"TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }"

Comment: added polyfills for keys and entries.  see if it works now